# Bad design of shift register

Tags: vhdl, shift-register

I've tried to make a shift register by myself. The syntax is correct but i'm not sure if this could a good design... i commented the statements that concern me...

```
    library ieee;
    use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
    use ieee.std_logic_misc.all;
    use ieee.numeric_std.all;

    entity ShiftRegister is
    generic(n : natural := 8);
    port(x : in std_logic_vector(n - 1 downto 0);
         clk : in std_logic;
     shift : in std_logic;
     w : in std_logic;
         y : out std_logic_vector(n - 1 downto 0));
end entity ShiftRegister;

architecture arch of ShiftRegister is
    signal y_int : std_logic_vector(n - 1 downto 0);
begin
    process(clk)
    begin
    if rising_edge(clk) then
        if w = '1' then
            y_int <= x;
        elsif shift = '1' then
            y_int(n - 2 downto 0) <= y_int(n - 1 downto 1);
            y_int(n - 1) <= '0';
        end if;
    end if;
    y <= y_int; 
    end process;
end architecture arch;
```

Answer (score 1):

You're right — you can't read from an `out` port in VHDL.

You need to create an internal variable that you use for the logic, and then assign its value to the output port:

```
architecture arch of ShiftRegister is
    signal y_int : std_logic_vector(n - 1 downto 0);
begin
    process (clk)
    begin
        if rising_edge(clk) then
            if w = '1' then
                y_int <= x;
            else if shift = '1' then
                y_int(n - 2 downto 0) <= y_int(n - 1 downto 1);
                y_int(n - 1) <= '0';
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;

    y <= y_int;
end architecture arch;
```

Comment: Shouldn't you init y_int? the statement `y_int(n - 2 downto 0) <= y_int(n - 1 downto 1);` doesn't look correct to me... is that right?

Comment: @Lukkio: You could initialize it, but that's a different question. In practice, it will be initialized using the `w` and `x` inputs. I was just addressing the OP's specific question. The shift operation itself is correct -- it's a right shift, with the new serial input (in this case, tied to `'0'`) going into the MSB.

Comment: Ok, thank you but do you mind if you correct the specific code correctly? Because i'm not quite sure it would work correctly. I mean when shift is enabled i don't understand what the system would perform...

Comment: @Lukkio: There's nothing to correct. It sounds like you have a different question, so please use the "[Ask Question](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)" button at the top of the page. You can include a [link to this question](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/191457/11683) in yours if it helps provide context.

Comment: You can read from an OUT port in VHDL-2008. Since nobody was using the tool designed for the job (Buffer ports) and various tools gave spurious warnings on them, the standards committee apparently gave in and added Buffer semantics to Out ports. If your tools don't support VHDL-2008,that's a different matter.

Comment: Let's say vhdl 93

Comment: @BrianDrummond: Ah, OK, that's good to know. I've been coding VHDL for a lot longer than that, so given the issues with `buffer` ports, I just got into the habit of creating a separate internal signal, and never found a reason to change. I guess this makes my answer moot, since there's nothing wrong with the original code.

Comment: You mean my code? Because, as i said the syntax is correct, but when i try to synthetize it doesn't work. However hanging around the web i've seen people using such assignment...

Comment: @Lukkio: What is the specific error that you're getting?

Comment: I don't know what's happening now... i have syntax error...

Comment: Ok a first error is the `else if` that should be `elsif`, after this the syntax error is the suspicious assignment i've being point out in this discussion.

Comment: @Dave : no, I feel your answer is still relevant. Support for VHDL-2008 is not as widespread as one might wish... the questioner may find this simulates but synthesis rejects it, for example.

Comment: Hi.. i changed the Code (look the original post) now i have no error syntax, but i can't compile it, any suggestions? (the code is basically the proposed one but with <code>elsif</code> instead of <code>else if</code>, i don't know if it is relevant or not...

Comment: Again, what is the specific error that you're getting? We're not clairvoyant here!

Comment: The first error is this <code>Error: extra positional option 'is' (CMD-012)
# if params are needed append something like
# "-param #n=>$bitwidth,width=>$ret_width#"
# to the previous non-comment line
link
Error: Current design is not defined. (UID-4)</code>

Comment: Get rid of the `is` at the end of the `process` statement.

Comment: i changed the code (instead of "process(clk) is" i deleted the "is")... it still doesn't compile, the error is the same.